# Multi-Otsu algorithm in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I was able to implement a single Otsu threshold using the following code:

```
// Return the DN that maximizes interclass variance in B5 (in the region).
var otsu = function(histogram) {
var counts = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('histogram'));
var means = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('bucketMeans'));
var size = means.length().get([0]);
var total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
var sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
var mean = sum.divide(total);

var indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size);

// Compute between sum of squares, where each mean partitions the data.
var bss = indices.map(function(i) {
var aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i);
var aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
var aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i);
var aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts)
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
    .divide(aCount);
var bCount = total.subtract(aCount);
var bMean = sum.subtract(aCount.multiply(aMean)).divide(bCount);
return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(
       bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)));
});
print(bss)
print(ui.Chart.array.values(ee.Array(bss), 0, means));

// Return the mean value corresponding to the maximum BSS.
return means.sort(bss).get([-1]);
};

var threshold = otsu(histogram.get('B5_histogram'));
print('threshold', threshold);

var classA = image.select('B5').lt(threshold);

Map.addLayer(classA.mask(classA), {palette: 'blue'}, 'class A');
```

Now I want to convert this algorithm into Multi-Otsu thresholding algorithm. Any idea on how to do that in Google Earth Engine?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a three-level Otsu on python-gee and it works fine. It's is far from optimized as I am not a programmer and didnt spend much time on this.

```
def computeThresholdUsingOtsutri(image,scale,zone): 
    bounds=zone
    minValue=-0.4
    imageEdge= image.clip(zone)
    buckets = 50
    hist = ee.Dictionary(imageEdge.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.histogram(buckets), bounds, scale,bestEffort=True,maxPixels=1000000000));
    threshold=ee.Algorithms.If(hist.contains('bucketMeans'), otsu_trimodal(hist), minValue)
    threshold=ee.List(threshold)
    threshold_k = ee.Number(threshold.get(0))
    threshold_i=ee.Number(threshold.get(1))
    print(threshold.get(0).getInfo())
    print(threshold.get(1).getInfo())
    output=image.addBands(
    image.gt(threshold_k.min(threshold_i)).And(image).lt(threshold_k.max(threshold_i))).selfMask().rename("water").clip(zone)
)        

    return output

def otsu_trimodal(histogram):
    histogram = ee.Dictionary(histogram)

    counts = ee.Array(histogram.get('histogram')); 
    means = ee.Array(histogram.get('bucketMeans')); 
    size = means.length().get([0]);
    total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]); 
    sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
    mean = sum.divide(total);
    #indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size); 
    
    def f_(i):
        global k
        aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i)
        aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]); 
        aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i)
        aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]).divide(aCount)
        
        bCounts=counts.slice(0,-1,k)
        bCount=bCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
        bMeans=means.slice(0,-1,k)
        bMean=bMeans.multiply(bCounts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]).divide(bCount)

        #cCount=total.subtract(aCount).subtract(bCount)
        cCounts=counts.slice(0,i,k)
        cCount=cCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
        cMeans=means.slice(0,i,k)
        cMean=cMeans.multiply(cCounts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]).divide(cCount)
             
        return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2))).add(cCount.multiply(cMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)))

    
    global bss_
    global k      
    bss_=ee.List([[0]])    
    k=ee.Number(-1)
    #while (k.getInfo())>= (indices.size().multiply(-1).getInfo()):
    while (k.getInfo())> (size.multiply(-1).getInfo()):
        indices = ee.List.sequence(1, ee.Number(size).add(k))
        intervariance=ee.List(indices.map(f_))
        intervar_=ee.Algorithms.If(intervariance.size().lt(size),intervariance.cat(ee.List.repeat(0,size.subtract(intervariance.size()))),intervariance)
        bss_=bss_.cat([intervar_])
        k=k.subtract(1)
    bss_=bss_.slice(1,bss_.size()) 
    bss_=ee.Array(bss_) 
    k_max=ee.Number(bss_.argmax().get(0)).add(1).multiply(-1) #### El argmax que no sean dos valores practicamente iguales
    i_max=ee.Number(bss_.argmax().get(1))

    return [means.get([k_max]),means.get([i_max])]
```